# Google goals: SEF urls or nosef urls?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I have a Joomla website with an extension SEF to make beautiful urls.

I want to configure my goals in Google analytics and I asked myself the following question:

Do I have to put a NONsef url or a SEF url?

I thought to put a SEF url because my non sef urls are not seen on the website. But my landing pages redirects to NON SEF thank you pages that immediately become SEF in the browser since SEF extension of JOOMLA does its job.

What do you think about?

I searched everywhere on forum, google et analytics support groups, but I can't find any answer to this question.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look in Google Analytics for the url that is used in the reports, that is the one you need to use for your goals. Alternatively you can look in the developer tools in your browser - go to the network requests tab, filter for requests that start with /collect (that is the GA endpoint) and look in the request url for the dp (document path) parameter.

If this will be the search engine friendly URl or not depends on when and how the redirect happens - if this happens before the GA code is executed you will get the "normal" Url, else the SEF url.